# SnapAR CameraKit lens not loaded error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { bootstrapCameraKit } from "@snap/camera-kit"

const CameraKitComponent = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null) // Reference to the canvas element
  const [lensId, setLensId] = useState("43293650876") // State to manage the current lens ID
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null) // State to manage the camera session
  const [cameraKit, setCameraKit] = useState(null)
  const [lensConfig, setLensConfig] = useState({
    lensId: "43293650876",
    lensGroupId: "913dffcc-07d8-4f94-901f-297260c6c4a6",
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeCameraKit = async () => {
      const apiToken =
        "API TOKEN" // Place your actual API token here
      const cameraKit = await bootstrapCameraKit({ apiToken })
      setCameraKit(cameraKit)
      const liveRenderTarget = canvasRef.current

      if (!liveRenderTarget) {
        return
      }

      const newSession = await cameraKit.createSession({ liveRenderTarget })

      const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
      })

      await newSession.setSource(mediaStream)
      await newSession.play()

      setSession(newSession) // Save the session to state
    }

    initializeCameraKit()

    return () => {
      session && session.stop && session.stop()
    }
  }, [])

  const applyLens = async (lensId, lensGroupId) => {
    if (!cameraKit || !session || !lensId || !lensGroupId) {
      return
    }

    try {
      const lens = await cameraKit.lensRepository.loadLens(lensId, lensGroupId)
      console.log("lens", lens)
      await session.applyLens(lens)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading or applying lens:", error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lensConfig.lensId && lensConfig.lensGroupId) {
      applyLens(lensConfig.lensId, lensConfig.lensGroupId) // Update to pass lens group ID as well
    }
  }, [lensConfig, session, cameraKit])

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setLensConfig({
              lensId: "43293650876",
              lensGroupId: "913dffcc-07d8-4f94-901f-297260c6c4a6",
            })
          }
        >
          Load Lens 1
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setLensConfig({
              lensId: "50502080875",
              lensGroupId: "913dffcc-07d8-4f94-901f-297260c6c4a6",
            })
          }
        >
          Load Lens 2
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setLensConfig({
              lensId: "50507980875",
              lensGroupId: "913dffcc-07d8-4f94-901f-297260c6c4a6",
            })
          }
        >
          Load Lens 3
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CameraKitComponent
```

The above is the code of my component. What I am trying to do it loading different lenses in runtime based on the button clicked. It gives me the following error once in a while.  Error loading or applying lens: Error: Cannot apply lens 43293650876. It has not been loaded by the Lens repository. Use CameraKit.lensRepository.loadLens (or loadLensGroups) to load lens metadata before calling CameraKitSession.applyLens.  I did try different methods including making a generic CameraKit componenet which is loaded based on given props (id and lens group id)  Is there a way to make this work